# where is “万”？[invalid input syntax for integer: "1.1万"]

Tags: sql, view, cjk, greenplum

we are building a data processing platform and using Greenplum 6.8.1 as the backend database.

In our platform, there is a "Clean" action, users are able to process their uploaded dataset in some meaningful way, such as split the column, cast, and filter, etc.  But something unusual happened during the whole process, recently.

by the way, every user's operation will create a view in Greenplum. and that view will be created based on his/her last step action result.

for example, User **AA** uploaded a dataset like this. "*dataset.s_249_1626934066746*" (there are 1969 rows and there is do has "万")
[Dataset Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knVRF.png)

you can create this table by using this script.
[s_249_1626934066746 SQL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xeyzx3uNgnJnRabsIJ90vHpBxIc5AZt_/view?usp=sharing)

BTW, User **AA** wanna find a set of popular items (the top rating items). so **AA** has these following operations.

**AA** used the "人" splitting the column "评价人数" (means the num of rating) into "评价人数_拆分1", **AA** can get a new pseudo-mathematical meaning column "评价人数_拆分1".

since the pattern of data in "评价人数" is num + "人" + "rated" (e.g. 1.1万人评分 = 1.1万(Chinese 10,000 marker) + 人 + 评分)

So in backend, we create a view like this

```sql
CREATE VIEW pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588360 AS select split_part("评分人数", '人', 1) as "评分人数_拆分1",* from dataset.s_249_1626934066746
```

[first step snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0VPl.png)

Since in "评价人数_拆分1", there are still have some rows containing “万” (Chinese 10,000 marker), which is unable to compare, so **AA** just dropped it.

```sql
CREATE VIEW pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588402 AS SELECT "评分人数_拆分1","pub_info","评分","name","播放弹幕追番","url","评分人数","_record_id_" FROM pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588360 WHERE ("评分人数_拆分1" !~ E'万' OR "评分人数_拆分1" IS NULL) OR "评分人数_拆分1" = ''
```

[second step snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAuOH.png)

And it works, the whole view only has 1756 rows, and all rows containing "万" are gone.

Now, **AA** wanna convert column "评分人数_拆分1" into a numeric type, so that **AA** can do something filtering in later time.

in the backend, we cast it into a bigint type.

```sql
CREATE VIEW pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588419 AS SELECT CAST("评分人数_拆分1" as bigint),"pub_info","评分","name","播放弹幕追番","url","评分人数","_record_id_" FROM pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588402
```

[third step snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8z4L.png)

Now, when **AA** selected those rating numbers bigger than 3000, there is an exception raised.

```sql
select * from pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588419 where "评分人数_拆分1" > 3000 --invalid input syntax for integer: "1.1万"
```

[invalid input syntax for integer: "1.1万"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Trh3.png)

Why? where is "万"？ so curious why "万" is still exist in some place.

=============================================

Some people like me, trying to find the problem, and we found if we continue to convert column "评分人数_拆分1" into decimal type, and do the select query again, it works again.

```sql
CREATE VIEW pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588437 AS SELECT CAST("评分人数_拆分1" as decimal),"pub_info","评分","name","播放弹幕追番","url","评分人数","_record_id_" FROM pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588419
```

and then

```sql
select * from pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588437 where "评分人数_拆分1" > 3000 --works （first convert INT， then DECIMAL）
```

Why? where is my "万"?

[why it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4AsM.png)

================================================

And we tried another method, if we directly convert column "评分人数_拆分1" into decimal type, it failed again.

```sql
CREATE VIEW pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588439 AS SELECT CAST("评分人数_拆分1" as decimal),"pub_info","评分","name","播放弹幕追番","url","评分人数","_record_id_" FROM pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588402
```

and raised the same error invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1.1万"

```sql
select * from pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588439 where "评分人数_拆分1" > 3000 --invalid input syntax for type numeric: "1.1万"
```

I wanna cry.

All sql are available from this like [SQL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18aYJanJZ8qMQhrNCxF5tQu7bLR2ZB5sk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't know much about sql, but you may try to do a string replacement before convert to int. You need replace "万" by "e4" and "亿" by "e8". "1.1e4" would be a valid floating point number in many platform. And round it to integer later.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this deserve a cry.

You select from a view not a table:

```
CAST("评分人数_拆分1" as bigint)
```

That means the real cast is done when you do select from the view.

The error you saw says the "评分人数_拆分1" has something like "1.1万" and can not be casted to bigint.

You should maybe write a sql function to convert strings like this to a bigint. However this is your job and people here will only give you the direction and will not do it for you.

Comment: Thank your sir, really appreciate your advice, I will do that. But I am still curious why it will work after i convert column type twice? it doesn't make sense to me.T_T

Answer (score 0):

LOL,

i dont know why but it works.

```sql
select * from pipeline.view_tclean_19280_1627009588419 where "评分人数_拆分1" > 3000::numeric
```